# Color tags of Files

Tags: pantheon-files, files

The elementary OS file browser (Pantheon Files) allows us to tag the folders name with colors.

I would like to change those colors and/or rearrange them.

Does anyone have any idea how? Which file to edit?

Thanks to any kind human that may be of any help. :)

Answer (score 4):

The colors are hard-coded at the moment in /libcore/gof-preferences.vala in the source tree so cannot be changed through the user interface or by changing a setting or config file.